# How do I gain microphone access through a download while using annyang

Tags: javascript, annyang

I have a program that I'm working on that requires to gain microphone access through the browser (javascript) while using annyang and speechkitt to make a little button on the bottom corner.

Though I have annyang (which is supposed to gain microphone access itself),
I still can't have the program "ask for" access to the microphone

Comment: annyang requires SSL to work, otherwise it won't even ask for mic access. check you've got this in place.

Comment: @MattSaunders Thanks!